# Mongoose - Filtrar por propriedade estrangeira

Tags: node.js, query, mongodb, mongoose

Boa tarde, estou precisando saber como posso fazer, utilizando o mongoose, para filtrar um modelo a partir de uma propriedade estrangeira. Por exemplo:

```
const Usuario = new Schema ({
    nome: { type: String, required: true },
    cargo: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: "Cargo"  
    }
})

const Cargo = new Schema ({
    nome: { type: String, required: true },
    sigla: { type: String, required: true}
})
```

Estou fazendo a consulta da seguinte forma (consultar usuarios que possuem cargo com sigla CDC):

```
const consultarUsuarioPorCargo = async () => {
    const usuarios = await Usuario.find()
        .select('nome')
        .populate({
            path: 'cargo',
            model: 'Cargo',
            match: {'sigla': 'CDC'},
            select: 'nome'
        })
}
```

Porém, ao invés de ele trazer só os usuários que possuem cargo com sigla CDC, ele traz todos os usuários e os que não dão match, ele preenche a propridade cargo com null.

Alguém sabe dizer como fazer esse filtro?

Comment: voce tentou passar o `CDC` como regex? e outra coisa, se esse foi o problema, fazer uma filtragem de array pelo proprio JS nao resolveria o problema?

Comment: Fazer filtragem no próprio JS acho que prejudicaria a performance .. Existem modelos com milhares de documentos.. O mongo iria retornar todos esses milhares de documentos e depois fazer a filtragem na aplicação.